# Show that $\int_0^{\infty} (\exp(x) - 2^{\sqrt 5 +1} + 1) (\coth(x) - 1) x^{\sqrt 5} dx = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, golden-ratio

Show that

$$ \int_0^{\infty} (\exp(x) - 2^{\sqrt 5 +1} + 1) (\coth(x) - 1) x^{\sqrt 5} dx = 0 $$

I wonder how many distinct methods there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using identity:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \exp (-n 2 x)=\frac{1}{-1+e^{2 x}}$$
$$\int_0^{\infty } t^{x-1} \exp (-a t) \, dt=a^{-x} \Gamma (x)$$
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } n^{-x}=\zeta (x)$$
so:

$\int_0^{\infty } \left(\exp (x)-2^{\sqrt{5}+1}+1\right) (\coth (x)-1) x^{\sqrt{5}} \, dx=\\\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\left(-1+2^{1+\sqrt{5}}-e^x\right)
   x^{\sqrt{5}}}{-1+e^{2 x}} \, dx=\\\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \int_0^{\infty } \left(-1+2^{1+\sqrt{5}}-e^x\right) x^{\sqrt{5}} \exp (-n 2 x) \, dx=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\int_0^{\infty } -x^{\sqrt{5}} \exp (-n 2 x) \, dx+\int_0^{\infty } 2^{1+\sqrt{5}} x^{\sqrt{5}} \exp (-n
   2 x) \, dx-\int_0^{\infty } \exp (x) x^{\sqrt{5}} \exp (-n 2 x) \, dx\right)=\\\sum
   _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(n^{-1-\sqrt{5}} \Gamma \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)-2^{-1-\sqrt{5}} n^{-1-\sqrt{5}} \Gamma \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)-(-1+2
   n)^{-1-\sqrt{5}} \Gamma \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } n^{-1-\sqrt{5}} \Gamma \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   2^{-1-\sqrt{5}} n^{-1-\sqrt{5}} \Gamma \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1+2 n)^{-1-\sqrt{5}} \Gamma \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)=\\\Gamma
   \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) \zeta \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)-2^{-1-\sqrt{5}} \Gamma \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) \zeta \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)-\Gamma
   \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) \zeta \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)+2^{-1-\sqrt{5}} \Gamma \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right) \zeta \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)=0$

Comment: A bit more detail would be nice. Like When you suddenly use gamma functions. It is correct though.

Comment: Actually I would love a proof without gamma or zeta.

Comment: @mick  "Actually I would love a proof without gamma or zeta". Wait for a better answer.